# Is there a a workaround when trying to use TailwindCSS and react-native-dropdown-select-list?

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

After much trial and error I determined that using the very handy react-native-dropdown-select-list in my React Native mobile app that there is  conflict with the TailwindCSS library. I get the following error:

Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins

I have tried all of the usual remedies for Tailwind including:

Setting the version as follows: "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2", AND "nativewind": "^2.0.11"
Deleting the node_modules and reinstalling packages

Any suggestions?